# How are Alert Triggers for Message Delivery Errors set up using the Twilio Console?

Tags: sms, twilio

I am building some SMS functionality into a CRM, and I cannot seem to get notifications for message delivery errors.

> 30001: Message Delivery - Queue overflow
>
> 30002: Message Delivery - Account suspended
>
> 30003: Message Delivery - Unreachable destination handset
>
> 30004: Message Delivery - Message blocked
>
> 30005: Message Delivery - Unknown destination handset
>
> 30006: Message Delivery - Landline or unreachable carrier
>
> 30007: Message Delivery - Carrier violation
>
> 30008: Message Delivery - Unknown error

Alert Triggers for both "Any Error" and "Error - 30007" are set up.

After they were set up, a few "30007 Carrier Violation" undelivered errors were created. They do show in the logs, however, they don't trigger any alerts, show in the current value column on the Triggered Alerts page, or show in the debugger.

When I visit the debugger, or even the dashboard, I see errors and warnings listed (i.e. 81011, 82001, etc.), but I see no 3000* errors, even though 3000* errors do exist in the programmable SMS logs.

Is there a setting I'm missing to see message delivery errors like I see other errors?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio support got back to me. They made a change to my account that fixed this.